# Recurrence relation from Thomas Algorithm

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, recurrence-relations, numerical-linear-algebra

Suppose that $$f_1 = -\frac{x}{1+x}$$ and $$f_{i} = \frac{-x}{2+2x+xf_{i-1}}, \ \ i>1$$

What is the general form for $f_i ?$ (An approximate solution would be interesting too).

Context: this corresponds to determing the coefficients for the [tridiagonal matrix algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix_algorithm) for the following matrix which appears in the Crank-Nicolson method

$$A= \begin{bmatrix} 
\ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \mathstrut^{.^{.^{.}}} \\
\dotsc & -\alpha & 2(1+\alpha) & -\alpha & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dotsc  \\ 
\dotsc & 0 & -\alpha & 2(1+\alpha) & -\alpha & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dotsc  \\ 
\dotsc & 0 & 0 & -\alpha & 2(1+\alpha) & -\alpha & 0 & 0 & \dotsc \\ 
\dotsc & 0 & 0 & 0 & -\alpha & 2(1+\alpha) & -\alpha & 0 & \dotsc  \\
\dotsc & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -\alpha & 2(1+\alpha) & -\alpha & \dotsc  \\
\mathstrut^{.^{.^{.}}} & \vdots &\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots  \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
With top row of equal to $\begin{bmatrix} 2(1+\alpha) & -2\alpha & 0 & ... \end{bmatrix},$ and bottom row equal to $\begin{bmatrix} ... & 0 & -2\alpha  & 2(1+\alpha)\end{bmatrix}.$

Here are the first few cases:

1. $f_1 = -\frac{x}{x+1}$
2. $f_2 = -\frac{x^2+x}{x^2 + 4x +2}$
3. $f_3 = -\frac{x^3 +4x^2 + 2x}{x^3 + 9x^2 + 12x+4}$
4. $f_4 = -\frac{x^4 + 9x^3 + 12x^2 + 4x}{x^4 + 16x^3 + 40x^2 + 32x + 8}$

So far, in general, it looks like we have
$$f_i = - \frac{x P(x^{i-1})}{Q(x^i)}$$
Where both $P(x^i)$ and $Q(x^i)$ are polynomials of degree $i$ with strictly positive coefficients. It would be interesting to have an algorithm to determine the coefficients of the polynomials. It would also be interesting to have an approximation for $f_i$ that works for small $x.$

Comment: Have you tried listing the first few cases?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Good point, I have added some more info

Comment: If $u=1+1/x,$ this becomes $f_0=-\frac1u,$ $f_{n+1}=-\frac{1}{2u+f_n}.$ Not sure if that helps, but it seems to make the recursion slightly simpler. If $g_n=-\frac1{f_n}$ then $g_0=u,$ and $g_{n+1}=2u-\frac1{g_n}.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thanks, that looks helpful, at the very least aesthetically.

Comment: I figured out the substitution $u=1+1/x$ because the limit of $f_n,$ if it exists, is $$\pm\sqrt{(1+1/x)^2-1}-(1+1/x).$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Letting $u=1+\frac1x,$ and $g_n=-\frac1{f_n},$ you get: $$g_0=u, g_{n+1}=2u-\frac{1}{g_n}.$$

We easily see that $g_n$ is the ratio of polynomials of $u,$ with the numerator of $g_n$ becoming the denominator of $g_{n+1}.$ So if we write: $g_{n}=\frac{p_{n+1}}{p_n},$ we have $$p_{0}=1, p_1=u, p_{n+2}=2up_{n+1}-p_{n}.$$

But this is a linear recurrence, and it can be written in terms of the roots od $v^2-2uv+1=0,$ $v_1,v_2=u\pm \sqrt{u^2-1}.$ Then there are constants (in terms of $u,$) $a,b,$ such that: $$p_n=av_1^n+bv_2^n.$$ Solving using $n=0,1$ we get $a=b=\frac12.$

So we actually get that $p_n$ is a fairly well-known polynomial sequence, the [Chebyshev polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials) of the first kind, $T_n.$

Then you get $$f_n=-\frac{T_{n}(1+1/x)}{T_{n+1}(1+1/x)}$$

If you write it explicitly in terms of $v_1,v_2$ you can multiply numerator an denominator by $v_1^{n+1}$ and get:

$$f_n=-\left(u+\sqrt{u^2-1}\right)\frac{\left(u+\sqrt{u^2-1}\right)^{2n}+1}{\left(u+\sqrt{u^2-1}\right)^{2n+2}+1}$$

When $u>1,$ this will converge to $$-\frac1{u+\sqrt{u^2-1}}=-(u-\sqrt{u^2-1}).$$

When $u<-1,$ it will converge to $-\frac{1}{u-\sqrt{u^2-1}}=-(u+\sqrt{u^2-1}).$

In both cases, it converges to a value in $[-1,1].$

When $u\in[-1,1],$ we can solve $u=\cos \theta,$ and you get:

$$f_n=-\frac{\cos(n\theta)}{\cos((n+1)\theta)},$$ which, depending on $\theta,$ might not even always be defined for all $\theta.$

Comment: @Jbag1212 Thomas Andrews has made an good contribution towards your goal of solving many parabolic equations. Note that the formula for $f_n$ is neat, but it is actually hard to utilize. You could compute all the cosines at once using vector operations, but then you need to read/write an entire vector which is what we would like to avoid. You might gain something by computing the cosines in blocks equal to length of a vector register, discarding asap, but the cosine function is not cheap. In contrast, doing a direct solve with the Thomas algorithm requires only basic arithmetic operations.

Comment: @CarlChristian For solving the Crank Nicolson algorithm $\alpha$ will be $D \frac{\Delta t}{(\Delta x)^2} >0.$ So $u=1+\frac{1}{x} >1.$ So I believe the difference in speed would be the difference between running the Thomas algorithm, which uses only basic arithmetic operations, or computing Chebyshev polynomials - but it does not look like I have $u=\cos (\theta).$ I imagine this difference would be minimal at best. I was hoping for something like $f_n = h(\alpha) * f_{n0}$ where $f_{n0}$ is independent of $\alpha$, but alas... Still very interesting nonetheless.

Comment: @Jbag1212. You are right, I had missed the critical detail of $u>1$.